# Android gallery image to base 64 string

Tags: android, encoding, base64

My app allows a user to select an image from the gallery and upload it to a server. Currently I can display the image but not upload it. I am not getting an error. Below is my code, I hope that it is clear.

```
public void submit_click(View view) {
    TextView err=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
    if (thumbnail != null) {
        // TextView err = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
        try{
            byte[] bitmapdata = imagetoArray();
            img = decodeUTF8(bitmapdata);

            if (updateImage() == true) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);    
            } else {
                err.setText("Error update image");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            err.setText(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }    
    }    
}

private boolean updateImage() {
    boolean status = false;
    TextView err=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
    String username = SessionManager.getMaps("user");
    String postData = "{\"UserImage\":\"" + img + "\",\"UserName\":\"" + username + "\"}";
    try {
        String domain = getString(R.string.domain);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(domain + "updateUserImage");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(postData.toString(), "utf-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (response != null) {
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            String json = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            status = Boolean.parseBoolean(json);
        }    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        err.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return status;
}

private byte[] imagetoArray() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TextView err=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
    try{           
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        err.setText(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return stream.toByteArray();
}


private String decodeUTF8(byte[] bytes) {
    String sw="";
    TextView err=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
    try{
        sw= Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        err.setText(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return sw;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you could try to isolate the part of your code that seems to be causing the problem - right now it's hard to follow such a large "wall of code".

Comment: Saying your problem is urgent isn't going to get you helped any faster. As Tobbe said, show what you have done to try to narrow down the problem. Explain in detail what is not working

Comment: Did you check the issue with the onclick handler? In the code you provided at first the handler was missing. Also what's happening when you follow the program flow? (hint: debugger!) What does the code and where breaks the functionality. And if you want people to use their time to help you, you could at least take the time to write "please" out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle a click event it would be a good idea to add a event handler to the button.

```
      submit.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submit_click(v);
        }          
      });
```

PS: Have a heart for your fellow programmer and read that: [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)